# QFileDialog doesn’t list tty* files in /dev/ on Linux

Tags: linux, qt4, tty, qfiledialog

I’m working on a Linux desktop application that needs to open a USB serial port, typically /dev/ttyUSB0 or /dev/ttyUSB1. I’m using QFileDialog to let the user select the file:

```
QFileDialog dialog(this);
dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::AnyFile);
dialog.setFilter(QDir::System | QDir::AllEntries | QDir::Hidden);
dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
QStringList fileNames;
if (dialog.exec())
  fileNames = dialog.selectedFiles();
```

When I direct the FileDialog to /dev, none of the files that I can see by typing “ls /dev -al” are there. The directories show up, but for example, this file doesn’t:

```
$  ls -al /dev/ttyS0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 2011-10-09 10:47 /dev/ttyS0
```

My user is a member of the dialout group:

```
$ groups
luke adm dialout cdrom audio video plugdev users fuse netdev bluetooth lpadmin admin sambashare
```

I’ve tried adding QDir::Readable and QDir::Writable and the above file still doesn’t show up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you read my post, you will see that I already have QDir:System as an argument to setFilter().  Is there another place this should be used?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but from some googling around, it seems that the library [qextserialport](http://code.google.com/p/qextserialport/) is recommended for handling serial ports in Qt applications.

Comment: @n.m. QDir::DefaultFilter is undefined.

Comment: @ClareMacrae I saw that, I'll have to look in to it more closely.  The qt developer forum has had no responses, so I'm inclined to think this is some sort of bug.  I filed a bug report here: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-21970

Comment: QDir::DefaultFilter should be defined as (-1), if not, just use -1.

Comment: Here are the documented filters: http://grip.espace-win.net/doc/apps/qt4/html/qdir.html#Filter-enum No mention of DefaultFilter or -1 is made.  I tried -1 and it didn't work, it gives the following compile time error: error: call of overloaded ‘setFilter(int)’ is ambiguous

Comment: Since `QFileDialog` is using `QFileSystemModel`, it is probably related to this other bug: https://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/browse/QTBUG-20968

Answer (score 2):

It amazes me how often people don't answer the question that was originally asked. I'll try not to do that here, if I can. I've done some homework on this problem since I'm having exactly the same issue. The short answer is that you can't use QFileDialog to reliably list and select nodes in "/dev". When you set the "QDIR::System" bit in the QFileDialog Filter using  `QFileDialog::setFilter(QDIR::System)`, you would expect that all the files in /dev would show up, but they do not. Admittedly, there are more entries than when it is not set, but most of the device nodes are still not displayed. It is clear that QFileDialog is doing some additional filtering behind the scenes, and that this filtering cannot be turned off in any obvious way.

On the other hand, if you use the QDir class with the QDir::System filter bit set, then in fact all of the /dev entries do appear in the entryList. For example, assuming that you already have a QComboBox named TTYDevices in your user interface, try something like this:

```
DevDir=new QDir("/dev","tty*",QDir::Name,QDir::System);
ui->TTyDevices->addItems(DevDir->entryList());
```

Then use the standard signals from QComboBox to detect and act on selection of the desired device node. By the way, ui is the standard Qt pointer to the instance of your parent window class and should be set up in the Window's constructor. Just make sure that you don't reference it before the constructor calls `ui->setupUi(this)`. If you do, the program will crash.

This trick provides identical functionality to QFileDialog, with the additional features provided by accessing the QDir object directly. It does mean that you cannot easily have the same familiar, uniform interface provided QFileDialog, but it works and is remarkably easy to code.